# Is it viable to use actual browser windows for detached panels in a web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, modal-dialog

I'm planning an application and I'm wondering if it would be possible to use actual windows (`window.open`) for pop-out style panels as an alternative to using the "virtual" sort of windows made using absolutely positioned elements. This would have the advantage of being detachable from the browser window so that users could take advantage of the additional screen space provided by multiple monitors.

But I'm unsure how well it would work. Some points:

- Would it be possible to keep the opened windows on top of the main application window, so that the detached panels wouldn't disappear behind the application itself
- Would it even be possible to open multiple windows from the same application, or would automatic browser security perhaps limit you to one?
- What about compatibility with the myriad of browser alternatives?

**To summarize, would the advantage of additional screen space outweigh the disadvantages of using browser windows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use popup windows. They will usually be blocked. It is far easier to give the user a link and ask them (as if giving instructions) to right-click and open-in-new-window, than it is to do a popup and ask the user to manually unblock it. (Even that is bad practice.)

> Would it be possible to keep the opened windows on top of the main application window, so that the detached panels wouldn't disappear behind the application itself
>   Probably not

Probably not.

> Would it even be possible to open multiple windows from the same application, or would automatic browser security perhaps limit you to one?

`window.open('http://www.google.com', 'win1')`, `window.open('http://www.google.com', 'win2')`

> What about compatibility with the myriad of browser alternatives?

Terrible, especially with popup-blockers, though it might work if your users only use one browser.

> To summarize, would the advantage of additional screen space outweigh the disadvantages of using browser windows?

I do not think this is a summary of the previous question. Multiple monitors seems to be a useful but rare use-case. I do not know of a website which requires multiple monitors. If you are making some sort of "monitor" (like the security monitor kind) or information-display kind of software, it might be worthwhile, but other websites make do with just 1 window which can be as large or small as the user wants.

That said, it is possible to use popup windows. Gmail for example uses them to create chat windows, which you can later "pop back in". It is not a required feature however, and more than one can quickly get unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you avoid window.open as many browsers and plugins will stop them. What you need are dialog boxes. See the following links for example of the jQuery UI one.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

You can find many other solution online that works without or with other libraries.

You can have as much as you like and can virtually do anything you would do in another window the advantage is that is that it will be much easier to handle communication between the dialog box and the main page that it would be using popup windows.

Comment: Common sense perhaps, but this answer doesn't really address any of my concerns. Also the communication part is no issue. Once the document element of a popup is wrapped by jQuery I have full control.

Comment: Sorry I assumed that all your concerns related to the usage of popup and as popup will blocked a lot (unless you force on users their browser/plugin settings) then it should be the first concern. The answer by ninjagecko is more precise.